# Why I got 'unable to resolve host' when I do 'sudo'?

Tags: command-line, sudo, hostname

Whenever I do 'sudo' I get an error saying 'sudo: unable to resolve host HP-Pavilion'. I recently change my hostname to "HP-Pavilion". I wonder if I screw up something.

```
$ sudo mkdir SourceCodePro
sudo: unable to resolve host HP-Pavilion
[sudo] password for mike:
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The question linked as duplicate actually isn't an exact duplicate. There the user has no host at all (`none` is displayed instead of hostname), while here it is not the case. The questions are related but not exactly the same, as is also apparent from the titles.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You changed the host name to `HP-Pavilion`, but it's not in the file `/etc/hosts`. So try to add the name to `/etc/hosts` file and also don't forget to add it to `/etc/hostname` file .

Your `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files will look like this,

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
HP-Pavilion
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   HP-Pavilion
```

Restart your pc to make changes work.

Comment: if you want to add the entry in the file, you can use `vi` command: 1. `sudo vi /etc/hosts` 2. press Insert key to be able to add content. 3. add the `127.0.1.1 YOUR_NEW_HOST_NAME_HERE` in the file. 4. press Esc, then `:wq` and then Enter, to save the file